# Git: Accidentally diverged two branches, and can't get them back together

Tags: git

So I really don't know how to use git very well, which has caused issues before. Let me try to explain what has happened:

There are two developers on this project, me and one other guy. I have been writing some code and want to check it in. Before checking in, I do a git pull. This doesn't work, and the error message says:

```
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 33 different commit(s) each, respectively.
```

I didn't really know what to do, so I just started messing around. I tried following some articles, which said that I should do merge or rebase to origin/master, but neither of those commands worked.

What was weird was that my code appeared to reflect the correct merge of both developers' commits, even though git didn't appear to say so. But after messing around some, I decided to do a
    git checkout origin
which took me out of all the branches. Now, git status says I'm not in any branch, and the only code I see is the other developers.

Now, keep in mind that when the branches diverged and had the 1 and 33 commits individually, that was the first time I had committed my changes.

Comment: Please do a `git checkout master` and `git merge origin/master`, and if it doesn't work be more specific about the error.

Comment: When I try git checkout master, I get the error: `error: You have local changes to '/some/file/path...'; cannot switch branches`, and when I run git merge origin/master, I get: `Already up-to-date.`

Answer (score 1):

Use `git diff` to see what your local changes are.  Local changes can be fixed in one of three ways:  you can wipe them out with a `git checkout HEAD -- filename`, you can stash them with `git stash save` and do a `git stash pop` after your merge, or you can commit them.  The last option is not recommended since you are not on a branch at the moment, which makes it harder to recover.

Once you have done that, then do your `git checkout master` and `git merge origin/master`.  For future reference, you probably want to commit before trying any pulls.